# What are some ideas for when "Inspect Element" in Chrome shows the expected behavior of CSS but actual result is different?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-webfonts, inspect-element

I have run into this a couple of times - I coded or modified a CSS template with a specific thing in mind, yet the browser displays it differently than intended.  When i use "Inspect Element" in Chrome, it shows the attributes I intended associated with that element, yet the browser is showing something different.  What are the possible options from here as far as figuring out the issue/getting the site to look how you want?

Before I had an issue that I can't remember exactly where it didn't display correctly in Chrome (but Chrome Developer Tools showed it as I intended), but it did display in another browser.

Now, I am having an issue where multiple pages on the same site have different fonts for the same menu although the CSS showing in Inspect Element is correct for all - the behavior is consistent between Chrome and Safari (haven't checked other browsers yet).

Comment: Could you please give us some of your code or a fiddle?

Comment: Or at least give a concrete example. This question is too abstract without examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check for `!important` on lower down lines. I think that happened to me once, and I don't think it put a line through my style that was being overidden. (It may have though it was a long time ago it happened.) The only way really around that if that's the case and if that `!important` is necessary is to add `!important` to your rule you want to overwrite with.  (Try to avoid using importants wherever possible though, because in most cases an important isn't necessary.)